# Crashing with "failed to scene-update in time" message while calling Core Data Operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

I am facing a strange issue "failed to scene-update in time". After downloading the data, I am storing it in to the Core Data. If the application is in foreground, everything will work fine. I am getting this crash only if I switch the app between states, background and foreground continuously while storing the data in to Core Data is in process. This crash will not happen in the debug mode.

I tried putting logs in different stages of Core Data operation method and I found the point where the app crashes actually. From the UI, I am using the following code

```
DatabaseManagerClass *database = [[DatabaseManagerClass alloc]init];
[database deleteDataFromFormTable:nil];

[database insertDataInChecklistTable:[self.responseDictionary valueForKey:@"checklists"]];

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mainThreadTask) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];`
```

The crash is happening inside the method "insertDataInChecklistTable". I checked the thread in which insertDataInChecklistTable is working. It is in main thread only. Can anyone could give some suggestion to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance,
Sree.

The updated code with perform block

```
-(void)insertDataInFormColumnsTable:(NSMutableArray*)responseArray withForm:(Form*)form
```

{
    AppDelegate *objAppDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc   = [objAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObjectContext *bgMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];

[bgMOC performBlock:^{
    for (int count=0; count<[responseArray count]; count++)
    {
        NSDictionary *columnDict = [responseArray objectAtIndex:count];

        Form_Column *formColumn = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Form_Column" inManagedObjectContext:moc];


        if ([columnDict valueForKey:FORMULA]!=[NSNull null])        //Added by mritunjay
            formColumn.formula = [columnDict valueForKey:FORMULA];
        else
            formColumn.formula=nil;

        if ([columnDict valueForKey:ASP_EDITABLE]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.asp_editable = [columnDict valueForKey:ASP_EDITABLE];
        else
            formColumn.asp_editable=nil;


        if ([columnDict valueForKey:CM_EDITABLE]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.cm_editable = [columnDict valueForKey:CM_EDITABLE];
        else
            formColumn.cm_editable=nil;

        if ([columnDict valueForKey:IM_EDITABLE]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.im_editable = [columnDict valueForKey:IM_EDITABLE];
        else
            formColumn.im_editable=nil;


        if ([columnDict valueForKey:SP_EDITABLE]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.sp_editable = [columnDict valueForKey:SP_EDITABLE];
        else
            formColumn.sp_editable=nil;

        if ([columnDict valueForKey:ASP_EDITABLE]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.dialog_row = [columnDict valueForKey:ASP_EDITABLE];
        else
            formColumn.dialog_row=nil;

        if ([columnDict valueForKey:INDEX]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.index = [columnDict valueForKey:INDEX];
        else
            formColumn.index=nil;

        if ([columnDict valueForKey:WEB_ONLY]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.web_only = [columnDict valueForKey:WEB_ONLY];
        else
            formColumn.web_only=nil;

        if ([columnDict valueForKey:LABEL]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.label = [columnDict valueForKey:LABEL];
        else
            formColumn.label=nil;

        formColumn.form_id = form.form_id;

        if ([columnDict valueForKey:ID]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.column_id=[columnDict valueForKey:ID];
        else
            formColumn.column_id=nil;

        if ([columnDict valueForKey:TYPE]!=[NSNull null])
            formColumn.type=[columnDict valueForKey:TYPE];
        else
            formColumn.type=nil;

        NSArray *selectionArray = [columnDict valueForKey:SELECTIONS];

        if ([selectionArray count]) {


            for (int count = 0; count < [selectionArray count]; count++)
            {
                Form_Sub_Columns *formSubColumns = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Form_Sub_Columns" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

                NSDictionary *subColumnDict = [selectionArray objectAtIndex:count];

                if ([subColumnDict valueForKey:ID]!=[NSNull null])
                    formSubColumns.column_id=[subColumnDict valueForKey:ID];
                else
                    formSubColumns.column_id=nil;

                if ([subColumnDict valueForKey:LABEL]!=[NSNull null])
                    formSubColumns.label=[subColumnDict valueForKey:LABEL];
                else
                    formSubColumns.label=nil;

                if ([subColumnDict valueForKey:REQUIRES_REMARKS]!=[NSNull null])
                    formSubColumns.requires_remarks=[subColumnDict valueForKey:REQUIRES_REMARKS];
                else
                    formSubColumns.requires_remarks=nil;


                if ([subColumnDict valueForKey:VALUE]!=[NSNull null])
                    formSubColumns.value=[subColumnDict valueForKey:VALUE];
                else
                    formSubColumns.value=nil;


                if ([subColumnDict valueForKey:DESCRIPTION]!=[NSNull null])
                    formSubColumns.description_name=[subColumnDict valueForKey:DESCRIPTION];
                else
                    formSubColumns.description_name=nil;



                if ([subColumnDict valueForKey:SELECTION_TYPE_ID]!=[NSNull null])
                    formSubColumns.selection_type_id=[subColumnDict valueForKey:SELECTION_TYPE_ID];
                else
                    formSubColumns.value=nil;

                [formColumn addSun_columnsObject:formSubColumns];
            }
        }
        [formColumn addFormObject:form];

        [form addColumnsObject:formColumn];

    }

    if([form.enable_attachment boolValue])
    {
        Form_Column *formColumn = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Form_Column" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

        formColumn.label = @"Add Attachments";

        formColumn.form_id = form.form_id;
        formColumn.index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:998];
        formColumn.column_id=[NSNumber numberWithInt:998];    // hardcoded if Attachment is Enabled.
        formColumn.web_only = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
        formColumn.type=[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];

        [form addColumnsObject:formColumn];

    }

    if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]) {
        NSLog(@"Main Thread inside block");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not main thread inside block");
    }

    NSError *error;

    if(![bgMOC save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

}

Comment: It would be helpful if you put the actual stack trace in your question so we can see what got called when.  I would also recommend **NOT** using `-performSelectorOnMainThread:` as that hides the stack trace before it (it basically gets wrapped in a try/catch).  `dispatch_async` is a better solution for getting something onto the main thread.  In general though, if you are writing data to Core Data **it should not be on the main thread**. Your blocking of the main thread is most likely causing this crash.

Comment: Marcus, Thanks for getting back to me. I understood what you said about performSelectorOnMainThread: The actual crash is not happening with the selector method invoked. The line before selector method invocation, a method which executes database operation. The crash is happening in that method. So I shouldn't call the database operation in main thread. Finally I put logs inside the db operation method and found the actual crash is happening at an addObject method of Coredata. Really hard to find out a solution for this.

Comment: Your crash is happening because you are blocking the main thread for too long and the OS is killing your app.  Put a breakpoint on the `-insertDataInChecklistTable` and see what thread you are on.  Are you on the main thread?  If not, post the code for that method.

Comment: Marcus, InsertDataInChecklistTable method is calling in MainThread.

Answer (score 1):

Processing data on the main/UI thread is **always** a bad idea and causes issues like this.

Your `-insertDataIntoChecklistTable` needs to be run on a background queue which means you should be:

1. creating a second `NSManagedObjectContext` which is a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`
2. associating it with your main context
3. using `-performBlock:` to process the data against that `NSManagedObjectContext`
4. saving when the processing is complete

That will get your data processing off the main queue.  Never, ever process data on the main queue.

Comment: Dear Marcus, This makes sense and I hope this tips will resolve my issue. I will try out and let you know. Right now, the NSManagedObjectContext initialized in the AppDelegate is using everywhere for coredata operations. So am I supposed to create new instance of NSManagedObjectContext for each coredata operation? Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: Marcus, I have edited my post by adding updated code with perform block. I tried in different ways performBlock as well as PerformBlockAndWait. performBlockAndWait works in the normal way, but the crash while going foreground and background is still happening. That means performBlockAndWait is blocking the Main Thread. In the case of performBlock, I am getting an exception "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x17d16330> was mutated while being enumerated.'". But I ensured that block is running in different thread.

Comment: `-performBlockAndWait:` does block.  That is what the `AndWait` part means :)  Getting the error "mutated while being enumerated" is not a Core Data error, that is a normal programming problem in that you are enumerating a collection and you are mutating the collection you are enumerating.  That is always bad and a separate problem from this SO post.